# OpenLayers v3.4 getting layer bounding box and CRS data from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I'm looking into OpenLayers v3.4 along with GeoServer.
I'm trying to collect the correct bounding box / extent data from a shapefile which I've already uploaded to GeoServer.

Here I am collecting the layer from the server.

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        preload: Infinity,
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Newcastle/wms',
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': "Newcastle:Newcastle_Coverage", 'TILED': true
        }
    })
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I would have thought I could have just called the extent from the layer.

```
var extent = vectorLayer.extent;
```

But alas, the extent is alwayd 'undefined' which is totally useless to me.
I then try to collect the data from using the WMSCapabilities function directly from the XML server download.

```
    var featurePrefix = '***';
    var featureType = '***';
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1&';
    var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();


    $.ajax(url).then(function (response) {
        //window.alert("word");
        var result = parser.read(response);
        console.log(result);
        window.alert(result);
        var Layers = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
        var extent;
        for (var i = 0, len = Layers.length; i < len; i++) {

            var layerobj = Layers[i];
            window.alert(layerobj.Name);

            if (layerobj.Name == "Newcastle:Newcastle_Coverage")
            {
                extent = layerobj.BoundingBox[0].extent;
            }
        }
    });
```

This works to some degree, it does return the bounding box of the defined CRS of the data.  In this case its EPSG:28356 (MGA56).  I know its MGA56 because I uploaded it and told it what it was.

What I need is to get the CRS details for shapefiles that I don't know.  How do I know if its MGA55 or MGA54 etc.  I cannot find a way to get this particular information out.

I did read a similar question like this they suggested to use layer.latlonBBOX which would return a geographic values. But the later version must have chanced as there is no latlongBBOX anymore.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595947/openlayers-v3-4-getting-layer-bounding-box-and-crs-data-from-geoserver ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because it is a duplicate of your question on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595947/openlayers-v3-4-getting-layer-bounding-box-and-crs-data-from-geoserver

Comment: You can't use the WMS functions to get at the information about the (native) input data (shapefile), because the WMS doesn't expose this information.   The WMS converts the shapefile to an image and you can only query the metadata about the WMS layer